# Backface culling in Unity

Tags: unity

I am a Unity noob trying to recreate something I did a long time ago in raw OpenGL.

[image]

I draw a scene normally `glCullFace(GL_BACK)`, and then draw the walls a second time with face culling flipped `glCullFace(GL_BACK)` and a semi-transparent alpha to everything.

So my question is how to achieve this in Unity?

Can I basically set up Unity to draw the scene twice, the second time with the new culling mode, a global alpha and perhaps only drawing meshes that are children of node with a particular tag?

Or is there some better or other way to achieve this affect?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it, but I'm pretty sure unity has an easy setting for this.  just a guess. the artwork on the image looks good, by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two materials for your walls. One normal, and one with a shader [in the Transparent queue](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-PassTags.html), [with alpha blending](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Blend.html), and [front-face culling enabled](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html), like so:

```
Tags {"Queue"="Transparent"}
Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
Cull Front
```

Attach both materials to your walls' renderer components (most renderers in Unity will accept an array of materials).

Unity will generate a pass for each material, drawing your walls with your opaque material in the Geometry queue, then later sorting & redrawing them with the translucent material in the Transparent queue, after all the opaque materials in the scene have been drawn.